# Pine Script - Dynamic History Referencing

Tags: pine-script

Let's say I have a barssince() script telling me how many bars ago something happened, I then want to know how many trades have occurred since this, so I use strategy.closedtrades[]... how do I make the history reference read the output of barssince?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `barssince()` it means you can detect the reset condition when it occurs, so will be simpler to keep a counter "manually" like this, resetting it to zero when the reset condition occurs.

Note that `change()` requires evaluation on every bar to return the correct result. That's the reason we pre-evaluate it before entry into the ternary:

```
resetCond = rising(close, 20)
var tradesSince = 0
newTrade = change(strategy.closedtrades)
tradesSince := resetCond ? 0 : newTrade ? tradesSince + 1 : tradesSince
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Just for my own understanding, can you break down what you meant by "That's the reason we pre-evaluate it before entry into the ternary", that kind of went straight over my head! lol

Comment: See our FAQ post on this: https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#why-do-some-functions-and-built-ins-evaluate-incorrectly-in-if-or-ternary--blocks